# Adding variable text to text file by line

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing, sed

I have a text file:

```
cat test1
ch140/121_------_T_201607061430
ch140/121_------_T_201611070840
ch140/121_------_T_201611071125
ch140/121_------_T_201611071235
```

I want add to this file line by line this text:

```
/121_------_T_201607061430
/121_------_T_201611070840
/121_------_T_201611071125
/121_------_T_201611071235
```

Result must be:

```
ch140/121_------_T_201607061430/121_------_T_201607061430
ch140/121_------_T_201611070840/121_------_T_201611070840
ch140/121_------_T_201611071125/121_------_T_201611071125
ch140/121_------_T_201611071235/121_------_T_201611071235
```

I used:

```
cat test1 | sed -e 's/ch140//' > test2
for a in $(cat test2)
do
????
done
```

What command can I use for this?
I tried using a `sed` command, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed 's/\/121.*/&&/' test1
ch140/121_------_T_201607061430/121_------_T_201607061430
ch140/121_------_T_201611070840/121_------_T_201611070840
ch140/121_------_T_201611071125/121_------_T_201611071125
ch140/121_------_T_201611071235/121_------_T_201611071235
```

#### Explanation

- `s/old/new/` replace `old` with `new`
- `\/121.*` match `/121` and whatever comes after it
- `&&` the matched pattern two times

You can add `tee` or use redirection to save to a new file

```
sed 's/\/121.*/&&/' test1 | tee test2
```

Answer (score 4):

The `paste` command does what `cat` does but side by side. The `-d ''` is for `paste` to use an empty delimiter, so there's nothing between the strings.

```
$ paste -d '' test1 test2 
ch140/121_------_T_201607061430/121_------_T_201607061430
ch140/121_------_T_201611070840/121_------_T_201611070840
ch140/121_------_T_201611071125/121_------_T_201611071125
ch140/121_------_T_201611071235/121_------_T_201611071235
```

Should the files be of unequal lenght, you might want to take a look at this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98945/a-better-paste-command) to prevent unsightly results.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `awk`:

```
$ awk -F'/' -vOFS="/" '{print $0,$2}' test1
ch140/121_------_T_201607061430/121_------_T_201607061430
ch140/121_------_T_201611070840/121_------_T_201611070840
ch140/121_------_T_201611071125/121_------_T_201611071125
ch140/121_------_T_201611071235/121_------_T_201611071235
```

Here I'm setting the input (`-F"/"`) and output (`-vOFS="/"`) field separators to `/`. This means that `$2` will be everything after the firdt `/` and until the next `/`. Since there's only one `/` per line, `$2` is the text you want to append. The script will print each line (`$0`) and then append the second field (`$2`).

You could also use the same approach in Perl:

```
$ perl -F"/" -anle 'print "$_/$F[1]"' test1
ch140/121_------_T_201607061430/121_------_T_201607061430
ch140/121_------_T_201611070840/121_------_T_201611070840
ch140/121_------_T_201611071125/121_------_T_201611071125
ch140/121_------_T_201611071235/121_------_T_201611071235
```

Alternatively, you could use the same approach as in [@Zanna's `sed` answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/853121/85695):

```
$ perl -pe 's#/.*#$&$&#' test1 
ch140/121_------_T_201607061430/121_------_T_201607061430
ch140/121_------_T_201611070840/121_------_T_201611070840
ch140/121_------_T_201611071125/121_------_T_201611071125
ch140/121_------_T_201611071235/121_------_T_201611071235
```